# Allocating values to a pandas dataframe based on upper and lower limits

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I ran into this problem lately and unfortunately, my knowledge of Python is insufficient to think of the solution.

Say I am a logistics manager for the Sydney - Melbourne route, and have the following modes of transport at my disposal, with their respective travelling times for the route:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()

Index    Transportation    Time
1        Plane             1:00:00
2        Rail              3:00:00
3        Truck             5:00:00
4        Bus               7:00:00
5        Ferry             9:00:00
```

Further, I have a list of clients with their preferences on how long they are willing to wait for their delivery, as well as specific cutoffs where they are agreeable in paying a premium for fast delivery.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

Index    Client    PremiumTime    MaxTime
1        Alan      1:00:00        3:00:00
2        Bernard   2:00:00        5:00:00
3        Cassie    2:00:00        7:00:00
4        Donald    3:00:00        7:00:00
5        Elijah    5:00:00        9:00:00
```

In this scenario, each mode of transport can only be assigned to one client, and assume that `len(df1) == len(df2)`. What I am trying to achieve here is to assign one mode of transport to every client such that I do not exceed their `MaxTime`, and at the same time look to try to satisfy as many clients' `PremiumTime` as possible.

Sample of possible desired output:

```
Index    Client    PremiumTime    MaxTime    Transportation
1        Alan      1:00:00        3:00:00    Plane
2        Bernard   2:00:00        5:00:00    Truck
3        Cassie    2:00:00        7:00:00    Bus
4        Donald    3:00:00        7:00:00    Rail
5        Elijah    5:00:00        9:00:00    Ferry
```

Note that I managed to achieve `PremiumTime` for both `Alan` and `Donald`, which is the best case scenario in this example.

Any help, or nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use:

```
d=df1.set_index('Time')['Transportation']
#create a mapping for time and transport
cond=df2.PremiumTime.isin(df1.Time)
#check if PremiumTime from df2 is there in time in df1
```

---

Then use [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for conditional mapping

```
df2['Transportation']=np.where(cond,df2.PremiumTime.map(d),df2.MaxTime.map(d))
print(df2)
```

---

***Output***

```
        Client PremiumTime  MaxTime Transportation
Index                                             
1         Alan     1:00:00  3:00:00          Plane
2      Bernard     2:00:00  5:00:00          Truck
3       Cassie     2:00:00  7:00:00            Bus
4       Donald     3:00:00  7:00:00           Rail
5       Elijah     5:00:00  9:00:00          Truck #note the diff in this row output
```

Comment: thanks for the help! however ````df2['Transportation']```` should only contain unique values. Is there an additional filter for this?

Comment: @AdrianY i guess there should be some way. Unfortunately cannot think of anything right now. I will try and get back to you on this. Meanwhile if it is urgent, i would suggest you take the 2 dfs, and the code so far which works, and post a fresh question may be(to get more attention-fresh questions get more visibility). Else if i find something to work with, I will comment you. Thanks..